# using usbguard append-rule

Tags: command-line, usb

I read the man pages but I am lost with the definitions. I am on 22.04 and want to use the usbguard CLI to add a permanent rule to allow all USB devices for a specific vendor id. Looking at the rule specification I expected this to work

```
 sudo usbguard append-rule allow 1234:* . .
```

Did not work and caused a not very helpful error message:

```
Exception (stoul)
```

I also tried

```
 sudo usbguard append-rule allow 1234:*
```

same result. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide your rule as a single argument. e.g.:

`sudo usbguard append-rule 'allow 1234:* . .'` (note the `'`).